# QtQuick: how to override window close event?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

My experience in Qt is about two weeks, excuse me if I happen to ask a stupid question.

My program uses QtQuick-based GUI. I initialise it in my *main.cpp*

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>

#include "VeryVeryImportantItem.h"

extern
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    qmlRegisterType<VeryVeryImportantItem>("com.my.stuff", 1, 0, "VeryVeryImportantItem");

    QQuickView      quickView(QUrl("MyView.qml"));

    quickView.show();

    QGuiApplication app;

    return app.exec();
}
```

And *MyView.qml* looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import com.my.stuff 1.0

Item VeryVeryImportantItem {
    id : veryVeryImportantItem
    ...
}
```

And *VeryVeryImportantItem.h* is as follows:

```
#include <QtQuick/QQuickItem>

class VeryVeryImportantItem : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void cleanup();
    ...
};
```

And now the problem. **How do I intercept close event on my root window/view, call VeryVeryImportantItem::cleanup(); and only after that close the application?**

What I've found out by now is that `QQuickItem::window()` can give me the pointer to the window I need and that the window has signal `QQuickWindow::closing(QQuickCloseEvent *);` and that in theory I can prevent the window from closing by manipulating the given `QQuickCloseEvent` object. **But it's not public, I don't have access to its methods!**

Ok. Another way might be that I could do something similar from QML. QML type `QWindow` has `closing(CloseEvent)` signal and if I set `CloseEvent.accepted` false in a slot connected to it that would prevent the window from immediate closing and enable me to call `veryVeryImportantItem.cleanup()` method. But then I have another problem: how do I get the reference to my root window if I've created it not in QML but in C++ start-up code.

I guess this is the very common situation and there obviously ought to be a well-defined way to handle this but I've been googling for some four hours and still haven't found any decent explanation.

Comment: VeryVeryImportantItem destructor is called when you close the window. You can make any cleanup here.

Comment: Well, I know that. But it doesn't suit my case. My architecture requires some signal exchange in order to accomplish cleanup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I guess this is the very common situation and there obviously ought to
>   be a well-defined way to handle this

Yes, one could say that.

The easiest thing to do would be to switch to using `QQmlApplicationEngine` and on the QML side `ApplicationWindow` as your root component.

Then you can simply use the `onClosing` signal handler to run your cleanup. I have a similar scenario, where the app would crash if closed before cleanup was invoked, and this approach works flawlessly.

```
//main.cpp
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl("MyView.qml"));
```

.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 720    

    BoxView {
        id: view
    }

    onClosing: {
        view.deleteView()
    }
}
```

Comment: How can one delay closing with question like "are you sure...?" using modal `Dialog`? Seems it is impossible in imperative style without additional boolean flag property.

Comment: @Orient - just add a `property bool canExit` and then in the close event `close.accepted = true or false` depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 5):

You can intercept the close event on QQuickView. To do it, create a derived class and overrides the event method:

```
class NewQuickView: public QQuickView {
public:
    NewQuickView(QUrl url):
        QQuickView(url) {}
public:
    bool event(QEvent *event) override
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Close) {
            // your code here
        }
        return QQuickView::event(event);
    }
};
```

on main, instance your new class:

```
NewQuickView quickView(QUrl("MyView.qml"));
```